# C# language compare

Tags: c#

i wan to compare two xml file and find their differences and similarities,

```
private void checkLanguage(string file1, string file2)
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc1 = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDocument xmldoc2 = new XmlDocument();

            XmlNodeList xmlnode1;
            XmlNodeList xmlnode2;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            string str = null;
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(file1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc1.Load(fs1);

            FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc2.Load(fs2);

            xmlnode1 = xmldoc1.GetElementsByTagName("data");
            xmlnode2 = xmldoc2.GetElementsByTagName("data");

            for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode1.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                str = xmlnode1[i].Attributes["name"].Value;

                for (j = 0; j <= xmlnode2.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (str == xmlnode2[j].Attributes["name"].Value)
                    {
                        lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        lblResult.Text += Environment.NewLine + xmlnode1[i].Attributes["name"].Value;   
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        label4.Text += Environment.NewLine + xmlnode1[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
                    }
                }


            }
}
```

my problem is the similar languange in both xml file list out in the difference field also..how to solve this..

can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Please make sample shorter and avoid mixing UI and logic at least for public samples...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem.  Can you rephrase it, or list current and desired output?

Comment: Could you just use a diff tool? http://prettydiff.com/

Comment: The OP is no longer registered or something... seems like there will be no response from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using linq to xml. Load both xml's and reachout to language value to compare. The same way for other tags.

Thanks
AHARI

Comment: I don't understand what this means. Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 0):

If doing a general diff is adequate I wouldn't use an XML parser at all. Instead, I'd use Google's DiffMatchPatch library. Here is some sample code below;

```
    var dmf = new diff_match_patch();
    var diffs = dmf.diff_main(FileOneAsString, FileTwoAsString);
```

After that you have a list of all the diff's. These are categorized as EQUAL, ADD, or DELETE. They show what transformations have to happen in file2 to arrive at file1. To make it more human readable I'd recommend using the semantic clean up method. There's an int you can set that determines how major the clean up is (I don't remember the name but you can find it easily if you go this route).

```
   dmf.diff_cleanupSemantic(diffs);
```

At that point you can see what's equal and what's not by looping over the diffs, and looking at the strings (the diff is an object with the type and the string).

The library can be downloaded here http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ and you can test out how much semantic cleanup you want to do using the diff demo.

If all you want is the differences in the two files this will be a lot simpler than using an xml parser.